# Angular, get component instance from inside a structural directive / from TemplateRef

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a structural directive which conditionally renders a given template or not based on some conditions and it's used like:

```
   <my-component *myMayBeShow>
```

The template is rendered by

```
const embeddedViewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

I can get the html nodes which were created:

```
embeddedViewRef.rootNodes[0]
```

But: how can i get the component instance "MyComponent" which were created by the embedded view?
I need somethink like:
https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetComponent
but that utils are designed for debugging and are avaialble only in dev mode.

Comment: What about using DI and simply "ask" for MyComponent in the Directive constructor? (e.g `constructor (private host: MyComponent) {this.host} `) The limitation would be that you need to know what component to ask for :/

Comment: I do not know the concrete type. 
Even if I would know the concrete type, and correct me if I am wrong: the DI won't help me here. When the structural directive is created and DI is performed, there is no instance of "MyComponent". This component gets created when I create the embedded view.

Comment: Oops, you're correct. Didn't realize it was a structural directive. So, once you get the reference to the Component, what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: The structural directive should not only be able to remove the component from the view / or add it, but also (optional) be able to "disable" it. Of course I can do that on html base, but that's not enough, one easy example e.g.:

<input formControlName='myInput' *myMayBeShow>

Should not html-disable the field, instead i want to disable the formControl via the directive